# Software uninstalled, apparently at random

Tags: 18.04, apt, uninstall

Some of my software got removed from my system, at random, as it seems to me.
I had atom, pycharm and django installed, but now its gone without a trace and I don't know why.

Some more background:
Before the software disappeared, I did not use my notebook for 1 or 2 weeks. Today I started it again, did apt-get update and apt-get upgrade. Then I wanted to start programming and noticed that all the above mentioned software is just gone.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, using a Lenovo ThinkPad... nothing special, I suppose...

How can this happen? Does anybody know?
I'm a bit puzzled.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You have learned a valuable lesson: To read your apt output carefully before agreeing to changes - that's your protection from unpleasant surprises.

Comment: @user535733 In the OP's defense, unless you know, from memory, every single dependency for every package installed on your system, "read your apt output carefully" is of limited utility.  It does, however, warn of "to be removed" without having to go through the entire file list.  Even the GUI update process does that, IIRC.

Comment: @ZeissIkon well, all the django and pycharm packages would add up to an impressive list. The length of that list alone would give me pause, even in a hurry...and I never hurry with apt.

Comment: @user535733 But it's often only the top level package that gets removed in the case I describe in my answer -- one conflicting dependency and the top level app goes.  You *do* get a warning for that, if you remember to check.

Comment: @ZeissIkon agreed, seems we've circled back to my original comment then.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this kind of thing happen when an `apt update` produces a conflict -- the "requested" package will be installed or upgraded, and conflicting packages (for instance, those that depend on a different version of an upgraded package) will be removed.

Unfortunately, fixing it can be time consuming; you'll have to check all the dependencies (at least at top level) for each removed package against the installed versions.  Chances are you'll find a single common library between the missing packages that has a higher installed version than the missing packages will work with.

Sometimes you can downgrade the upgraded packages, but it's usually preferred to try to find an upgrade for your missing packages.

This usually happens because your missing packages weren't installed from the core repositories for your OS, but rather from third-party repos or PPA sources, or compiled from source -- and the source of the missing packages was slower updating than the core repos, or simply no longer supports the version of Ubuntu you're using and will require you to upgrade your entire OS.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought --- Has the software really been removed? I've had the situation, with PyCharm specifically, that the icon has disappeared. In my case, the icon just needed to be re-created.

Comment: Yup, I searched for any pycharm files, couldn't find any. Same goes for atom and django